# Vibration when stopped or on brake

Tags: elantra

My  car is a 2017 Hyundai Elantra with 49745 miles on it. At times when I brake or slow down to brake at lights it vibrates and rumbles. What does it mean? I bought this car last April 2018 from Enterprise Car Sales.

Comment: Your car should have an OBD port. It would be useful to know what error codes are displayed. Your local auto parts store may well read the codes for free.

Comment: Does the vibration occur while the car is still moving forward, or after it has come to a stop? If while still moving forward, the cause is likely to be found in a worn, damaged, or excessive run-out brake disk or disks.

Comment: What vibrates?  Does the steering wheel feel like it is vibrating?  Does it only happen when you apply the brakes, or also when you let off the gas.  Or does it seem like an engine sound?  And is it in sync with your speed?  Slower vibration at slower speed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That just recently happened to my 2014 Chevy Sonic, turned out that it was a faulty O2 sensor that was making the computer add to much gas into the engine. I'd suggest getting it checked soon, I waited too long and had to rebuild my engine.